# chrome extension content script before tab-close or page change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a content-script that's initiated in my `background.js` with:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    var url = (new String(tab.url)).valueOf();
    if(url.indexOf("chrome") == 0 || url == undefined || url == 'undefined')
        return;
    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete') {            
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,
        {file: "js/control.js", runAt:"document_end"},
        function() { console.log("Control sent to page");
    });
    console.log("ChangeInfo " + changeInfo.status);
});
```

I need to execute a function before the page changes or the window closes. I've looked around and can't figure out how to do this. The closest thing I could find was:

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function () {
    someObjectDefinedInScript.afunction("stopping");
});
```

Because I got `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to work in the **content-script**.

But this returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Good old `window.onunload` will work from a content script.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `chrome.tabs.onRemoved` event to listen to Tab close (You should declare this listener on your background script).

More info: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved

Comment: Downvoted for incorrect first part of the answer: read carefully, this code is in the background script. Edit that out and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @Xan The first line of this answer looks correct to me. Perhaps you missed the "not" in "can not use"?

Comment: @RobW It is correct, but irrelevant. The question cites background code that injects the content script.

Comment: @Xan The question does not state that the code has to run in the content script. The fact that the question refers to the `chrome.runtime.onSuspend` event allows for answers that run in the background page as well (because this event does not exist in content scripts).

Comment: @Xan you were correct, I read wrong the question. I've improved the question and my answer for better understanding. Regards!